# Why can't I post to a band's Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

This question is about how to interact with formal Facebook pages for someone who has never used that site before.  I apologize if this question has been answered previously somewhere, but I could not find it.

I have used many forums over the years, but am finding Facebook to be extremely counter-intuitive.

I wanted to ask a question of fans of a given rock band that seems to have no formal, currently-active standard forum (I did find one, but the posts are very old and no one seems to be answering me there).  The band does, however, have an active Facebook page (very new posts there).  As I am not a Facebook user and have absolutely no desire to deal with "friend" requests and such, I created an account then immediately turned on all the privacy settings (friend requests only from "friend of friends" (there was no "none"), etc.), then posted my question to the given page.  Perhaps it is related to having done so (how the various privacy settings are set), but when I posted my question to the band's page via the "Write something on this page" box, it appears in some "visitor" area on the left then disappeared the next time I refreshed the page, as if it had ignored me.

Is there a formal approval process?  All forums I've used like that always tell you when that is the case (something like "Your post will appear within 24 hours after being reviewed").

Do I have to allow "friend" quests and whatnot in order to do something as simple as making a post to a public page?  The page does seem to be more of a news feed more than a discussion area (almost all the topics seem to have picture content and such), but on the other hand it does seem like a variety of people are posting that aren't necessarily working for the band or anything like that.  I wanted to use the "message" tool, but not sure where to find their identifier/address/whatever to do so.

I am extremely confused.  Would someone please explain how to interact with these formal/professional/whatever Facebook pages?

Comment: It sounds like you did it right. If your message is no longer showing up, they may have deleted it. You can also check in their main feed, there should be a "posts by page" item at the top, you might be able to change that to another option to see others' posts.